# C++ CLI / SOKET

Tags: c++

Может кто знает где можно почитать про класс Socket?

То что в MSDN там пару строк написано и какой то не понятный пример, это мне не о чем не говорит.

Хотелось бы узнать какие методы и свойства в каких случая применяются, попрактиковаться с работой http/ip/tcp/udp.

Пускай даже англоязычные сайты/статьи.

Просто в гугле ничего найти не могу, а на форумах как обычно, только посылают в гугл или куда подальше) )

Comment: Попробуйте сначала без классов (просто на Си).

Почитайте для начала [это на русском](http://kpnc.opennet.ru/sock.pdf) или [это на английском](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#intro), а потом можно [углубиться сюда](http://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html), ну а далее потренируетесь писать программы и уже сами сообразите какие запросы формулировать в гугле.

Comment: Если вы пишете на C++/CLI, немедленно переходите на C#.

Обычно вам не должны быть нужны настолько низкоуровневые штуки. Расскажите, какую настоящую задачу вы решаете.